# Jenkins docker running in the container but not launching in web browser

Tags: docker, jenkins

On my Redhat7linux  docker host, i have created a jenkins container by pulling the jenkins official image from docker hub and i was able to bring the jenkins container up & running by executing the command:

```sh
docker run -d -p 50000:8080 -v $PWD/jenkins:/var/lib/jenkins -t jenkins_master
```

and i could see the jenkins is up when i checked the logs using the `docker logs {containerID}` but when i try to launch it in web browser with `{hostip}:50000`, I couldn't access it as it throws "The site cant be reached", and since my container is running inside a company network, should I either open/enable that port 50000 or do I need to set any proxy in the docker host?

Am I missing something here?

Here are the outputs of the docker command:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The official image provide the following command :

```sh
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

It seems that both ports `8080` and `50000` have to be exposed.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the docker run command to run the container, check the status of your container.

> docker container run -p [YOUR PORT]:8080 -v [YOUR
> VOLUME]:/var/jenkins_home 
> --name jenkins-local  jenkins/jenkins:lts

[image]

you can then access it using localhost:[YOUR PORT]